# Why the ideal norm is multiplicative

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, normed-spaces

Let $I\subseteq B$ be an ideal, we define the ideal norm of $I$ as the ideal in $A$ generated by the elements $N_{E/K}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha \in I.$
We denote it by $N_{E/K}(I).$

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a DVR. I want to see that the norm is multiplicative.

I know I have to use some kind of theorem that reduces to local cases, but I don't know how to manage this.

Of course if $I,J$ are principal ideals, then $N_{E/K}(IJ)=N_{E/K}(I)N_{E/K}(J)$ because of the multiplicity of the "number" norm, but, why this is happening when there are no principal ideals?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 5):

By the Chinese remainder theorem it is enough to consider ideals of the form
$I = P^n$ for prime ideals $P$. We show that $N(P^n)=N(P)^n$ by induction.
The case $n=1$ is clear. Assume now that it holds for $n$. We want to show it for $n+1$. The map $A_P/P^{n+1}\rightarrow A_P/P^n$ is surjective with
kernel $P^n/P^{n+1}$, which is a $1$-dimensional $A_P/P$-vector space
having $N(P)=|A_P/P|$ elements. It follows that
$$
N(P^{n+1})=N(P^n)N(P)=N(P)^{n+1}.
$$

Comment: your answer is for the case $A = \mathbb{Z}$, and $B$ the ring of integers of some number field, right ?

Comment: Yes, for $\mathcal{O}_K$ the ring of integers of a number field $K$. The duplicate is more general (and therefore better):

Comment: Well, that is the reason I left the answer there. Perhaps the OP finds it useful.

Comment: This is not going to happen in the general case, isn't it? I wanna make it for the general general case. I know may appear the localization but I don't know how to use it.